# Vim indentation incorrect for Javascript nested objects

Tags: javascript, vim

I am using `auto-indent` and also `vim-javascript` for my javascript writing in Vim. However, I can not get javascript objects to indent correctly. For instance:

This, which I indented manually:

```
var NetworkSchema = new Schema({
    'timeStamp' : { type : Date, index: true },
    "avaiable" : Boolean,
    "status" : String,
    "metrics" : [ { "txDropped" : { "data" : Number,
                           "type" : String,
                           "unit" : String
                          }
                   },
                   { "txErrors": { "data" : Number,
                           "type" : String,
                           "unit" : String
                          }
                   },
                   { "txOverruns": { "data" : Number,
                           "type" : String,
                           "unit" : String
                          }
                   }
                  ]
});
```

looks like this, when auto-indented using `gg=G`:

```
var NetworkSchema = new Schema({
    'timeStamp' : { type : Date, index: true },
    "avaiable" : Boolean,
    "status" : String,
    "metrics" : [ { "txDropped" : { "data" : Number,
        "type" : String,   
        "unit" : String    
    }                     
    },             
    { "txErrors": { "data" : Number,
        "type" : String,   
        "unit" : String    
    }                     
    },             
    { "txOverruns": { "data" : Number,
        "type" : String,   
        "unit" : String    
    }                     
    }              
    ]             
});
```

How can I make the indentation correct automatically for nested objects?

Comment: "Correctly" is subjective. You may have to fix it yourself, this could be a good starting point: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code#Different_settings_for_different_file_types

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

That's a question for [vim-javascrit's issue tracker](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript/issues).

Anyway, I use [js-beautify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/js-beautify) to format my JavaScript:

```
command! -buffer -range=% Format let b:winview = winsaveview() |
  \ execute <line1> . "," . <line2> . "!js-beautify -f - -j -B -s " . &shiftwidth |
  \ call winrestview(b:winview)
```

Use the following command to format the entire buffer:

```
:Format
```

Use the following command to format the lines covered by the current visual selection (the `'<,'>` range is automatically inserted for you):

```
:'<,'>Format
```

Use the following command to format the lines covered by an arbitrary range:

```
:23,89Format
```